# laravel relation - variable local key and eager loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, has-many

[My situation - logical data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uFh2.jpg)

I have situation like this:

- Entity1 can have many other entities1
- If entity1 is not root then it belongs to root entity1
- If entity1 is root then it have one descriptor

Now I want to access to descriptor model from entity model. If entity is not root then it should have its root entity descriptor.

I have done something like this:

```
class Entity1 extends Model {
   public function descriptor(){
     if ($this->root_id)
         $key = 'root_id';
     else
         $key = 'id';
     return $this->hasOne(Descriptor::class,'id',$key)
   }
}
```

But now I have a problem with eager loading descriptor.
How to solve problem with eager loading?

Comment: `Entity1::with('descriptor')->get();` any problem?

Comment: Problem is when entity1 is not root in the chain. In that case root descriptor shoud be returned. When eager load null is returned instead.